# How reliable is to use client-side XSLT in mobile browsers

Tags: xslt, mobile, client-side

I know pretty well the state of xslt support by major desktop browsers. In short, this support  is quite decent. And what major mobile browsers. Do they support client side XSLT? Are there any pitfalls and/or limitations?

Comment: AFAIK SaxonCE (XSLT 2.0) has been demoed 4 months ago working on an iPhone. It probably works on all major mobile browsers, as it is cross-compiled to Javascript.

Comment: What is SaxonCE? A javascript library?

Comment: Saxon-CE is an XSLT 2.0 processor developed by Saxonica, it includes extensions for Javascript and DOM interoperability. Saxon-CE is implemented in JavaScript and deployed on the web host server like any other JavaScript library. Two HTML Script elements are used, the first references the Saxon-CE JavaScript library, the second declares the XSLT entry-point ('data-source' or 'data-initial-template'). More details on the Saxonica site.

Comment: @pgfearo, helas, in that case it is not the answer to my question. I've asked about pure browser support.

Comment: @shabunc I haven't tried to strictly answer the main question (just the 'What is SaxonCE' query in your comment), perhaps you should clarify what you mean by 'pure browser'. Are you saying that something like jQuery isn't a 'pure browser' solution either? Saxon-CE still runs on the client - the browser downloads the required JavaScript the first time the HTML page is loaded - thereafter the cached version is used.

Comment: @pgfearo  - imagine javascript html or css parser - it definitely can be done. nevertheless, there is such thing like native support. so, here is my clarification)

Answer (score 1):

I should probably make this a comment since I haven't done this in over a year but client side  XSLT was poor then, sadly, and nowhere near as good as the desktop. I don't think it's improved enough today. It's the reason I won't consider its usage now and it's a shame on all browser vendors that they don't offer great XML family support in all areas.

Comment: what exactly problem have you encountered? Off the top off my head, if we are talking about basic, core xslt functionality, few years ago there were some problems with client side implementation of xsl:key.

Comment: @shabunc I wish I could remember but I was frustrated when some basic  working code was not supported in Android.

Comment: Android doesn't support it at all currently. Though, Firefox and Opera added support to it. Though, most users won't install a new browser to it, but use the standard one coming with the phone ... which doesn't support it.